# SQL Server 2008. I created an instance of SQL Server. My user domain has since changed. How do I reconfigure SQL for my new user domain?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I created an instance SQL Server on my local machine.
Then my login changed and I was assigned a new domain.
As a result, I need to reconfigure SQL Server.
The owner of the instance is still myself with the old domain. I need to change that to the new domain.
Then I need to change my .Net apps so that they can connect to this instance.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql server is 'nothing' more than a windows service.  By owner of instance, perhaps you mean the account under which the ms sql server service is running?  If so, manage computer, services, choose the service with the instance in question, set the logon name & password.

- [Changing the service account](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283811)
- I just plain don't like this answer here --> [Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/Q_20622559.html)
- If you just like learning stuff, you might enjoy this one: [NYC DBA](http://nyc-dba.blogspot.com/2007/01/changing-domain-for-sql-2005-cluster.html)

Your .Net apps --> depends on "how" they are configured now.  If they are on the same box and were using something like (local), nothing need be changed.  If they were configured to point to the machine name, such as machine.old_domain.com, then simply changing them to machine.new_domain.com.  If they are configured to point to machine and the name of the machine didn't change, no configuration changes needed.

This are just starter answers.  I've never had this happen to me.  Good luck my friend.

Comment: Good references, thank you for that. That said, the simplest solution appears to be uninstall and reinstall, which is what I have done. Fortunately for me I can get away with this on my local machine.